# anaconda spyder cannot show the chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, anaconda

when I run the file, the chart is not displaying in my console.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMQEE.png)

error as `matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x113d356d0`

how can I solve this ? I run Spyder in my macbook(macOS sierra) and the error also come with my windows 10 system.

here is my code :
I ran it successfully in my old macOS(capitan), did that affect?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMQEE.png)

Comment: what is your code?

Answer (score 1):

We need to see your code to give you the exact solution (so please do so), but from what I see in the picture it *seems* like you're doing something like `print(some_plot_object)`. You have to do `plt.show()` to actually display the graph. Like so:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

No printing!

Comment: sorry I put that up so late , could you check my code again? I think it may have a relation with my macOS(capitan) system because I ran it successfully until I'm using (Sierra)